# Oracle Join - Which is faster - using the whole table or a subquery that has specific columns needed in the table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, syntax, inner-join

**I am really new into optimizing queries. Could you please advise which INNER JOIN runs faster?**

**Please note that i am using two different ways of inner join syntax(have same # of records)**

1.) INNER JOIN of subqueries that have DISTINCT and selected columns only from  its respective table

```
select 
fac.fac_id ,
dept.dept_id ,
wk.week_id ,
sum(case when TRIM(fpl.MEASURE) like '%Salar%Wage%' then DATAVALUE else 0 end) WAGES_AMT,
sum(case when TRIM(fpl.MEASURE) like '%Tot%Man%hour%Ret%' then DATAVALUE else 0 end) MANHRS_QTY,
fpl.md_cycle_nbr ,
fpl.md_load_dt 
from  
    EAS_STG.FPA_PLAN_LABOR fpl 
    INNER JOIN
        (
          select distinct(dept_nbr), dept_id
          from department_D 
          where regexp_instr( Dept_nbr,'([^0-9])') = 0
         ) dept 
         ON TO_NUMBER(TRIM( 'D' FROM fpl.department)) = TO_NUMBER(dept.dept_nbr)
      INNER JOIN
         (
          select distinct(FAC.FAC_NBR), fai.fac_id
          from FACILITY_D fac, FACILITY_ALTERNATE_ID fai
          where fac.fac_id = fai.fac_id 
          and fac.company_id = 1101      
         ) fac
         ON TRIM(REPLACE(fpl.facility, 'Fac-')) = fac.fac_nbr
      INNER JOIN
         (
          select distinct(wk_hierarchy_id) week_id from DAY_HIERARCHY_D
         ) wk ON TO_NUMBER(TRIM(REPLACE(fpl.scenario, 'Plan ')) || TRIM(REPLACE(fpl.time, 'Wk '))) = WK.week_id
GROUP BY
fac.fac_id ,
dept.dept_id ,
wk.week_id ,
fpl.md_cycle_nbr ,
fpl.md_load_dt 
;
```

2.) INNER JOIN of the whole table without the selected columns

```
SELECT fac.fac_id
     , dept.dept_id
     , d.wk_hierarchy_id week_id
     , SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(fpl.MEASURE) LIKE '%Salar%Wage%' THEN datavalue ELSE 0 END) WAGES_AMT
     , SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(fpl.MEASURE) LIKE '%Tot%Man%hour%Ret%' THEN datavalue ELSE 0 END) MANHRS_QTY
     , fpl.md_cycle_nbr
     , fpl.md_load_dt 
  FROM EAS_STG.FPA_PLAN_LABOR fpl
  JOIN department_d dept
    ON TO_NUMBER(TRIM( 'D' FROM fpl.department)) = TO_NUMBER(dept.dept_nbr)
  JOIN facility_d fac
    ON TRIM(REPLACE(fpl.facility, 'Fac-')) = fac.fac_nbr
  JOIN facility_alternate_id fai
    ON fac.fac_id = fai.fac_id 
  JOIN day_hierarchy_d d
    ON TO_NUMBER(TRIM(REPLACE(fpl.scenario, 'Plan ')) || TRIM(REPLACE(fpl.time, 'Wk '))) = d.wk_hierarchy_id
WHERE fac.company_id = 1101
   AND REGEXP_INSTR(dept_nbr,'([^0-9])') = 0
GROUP BY fac.fac_id
     , dept.dept_id
     , d.wk_hierarchy_id
     , fpl.md_cycle_nbr
     , fpl.md_load_dt
;
```

Comment: Check the execution plans, but I doubt that there will be a difference. I would always go for the second query because it's a lot easier to read and maintain.

Comment: The major "brake pad" in your query is not the way how you join your tables but the conditions as `regexp_instr( Dept_nbr,'([^0-9])')` or `ON TO_NUMBER(TRIM( 'D' FROM fpl.department)) = TO_NUMBER(dept.dept_nbr)` or `ON TRIM(REPLACE(fpl.facility, 'Fac-')) = fac.fac_nbr` and `ON TO_NUMBER(TRIM(REPLACE(fpl.scenario, 'Plan ')) || TRIM(REPLACE(fpl.time, 'Wk '))) = WK.week_id`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thanks! i checked the plan and there are no significant difference with them.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - yes, it is a code requirement and couldn't help with that. :)

Comment: If you are stuck with these join conditions and you're concerned about performance, I would strongly suggest looking into creating some function-based indexes.

Comment: Databases are an applied science (as opposed to theoretical). As such, in most cases, it is best to try the different solutions on your actual data and see which works best. There may be theoretical reasons why something should work better than something else - those theoretical reasons will give you the right answer about 50% of the time.